# FB login to WSO2 IS using Custom Grant type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wso2, facebook-oauth, wso2-identity-server

We are developing a mobile app which has a login with FB feature. The App is handling the FB authentication using SDK supplied by FB.  The App is then calling WSO2 IS oauth/token endpoint to generate the IS access token for the user linked to the email address that is verified by FB. The App will supply the FB access token and user email.

IS need to verify the FB access token, fetch the user linked to that email and then  issue a WSO2 IS access token.

To this end we have implemented a custom grant type by extending the AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.

The question that i have is, How to fetch the FB client ID and FB client secret that is configured in Identity provider from  the custom grantHandler. Any help will be appreciated.

PS: We tried using the in built FBFederatedAuthenitcator but ran inot problems because it is redirection based. We need a solution without any user aggent redirects.